# How to calculate revenue performance for same number of weeks for historical quarters including current quarter?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgresql and trying to build revenue snapshot which provides revenue performance for historical as well as current quarter.
How to calculate revenue performance for same number of weeks for historical quarters including current quarter? Below is the snpashot.

```
Acct    Quarter                        Quarterly_Revenue  Revenue_at_8_weeks    
1234    Q12019 At the end of 8 weeks                $5,300      $4,800  
1234    Q22019 At the end of 8 weeks                $5,200      $4,700  
1234    Q32019 At the end of 8 weeks                $5,100      $4,600  
1234    Q42019 At the end of 8 weeks                $5,000      $4,500  
1234    Current Quarter(Q12020)At end of 8 weeks    $5,000      $5,000
```

Comment: Apologies. Since this is my first time, I'm struggling a bit here. What I need is the output from column Revenue_at_8_weeks

Comment: Hello Subhahan Syed, welcome to Stack Overflow. I would be good if you could provide sample data that corresponds to your expected results to clarify your requirement (a few rows of sample data is usually enough, with the *corresponding* expected results).

Comment: @GMB, added sample data view in the post by editing it. Hope it works